# Compare Strings in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Heres my code (so far):

```
var=$(sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0)
echo "$var"

if [ "$var" == "OK" ]
    then
        echo "Everything is fine"
    else
        echo "Not OK"
fi
```

As the output of this script is "OK" it should also write "Everything is fine", as the serial port sends "OK". But I only get the "Not OK" message which is strange for me. The first echo says "OK" but if I want to compare the string its not "OK" anymore.

Can anyone help me (I'm a linux newbie)

Comment: Does the script have a shebang (`#! /bin/bash`)? How are you running it?

Comment: Yes it has a shebang

Comment: If `var` is `yes` and you are running `bash` then your script is ok..whats the output of `echo "$var" | od -c` ?

Comment: The Output is "OK", but there might be Whitespaces

Comment: there is command "eval" too, here is a link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is tab or whitespace in the `var`. Pipe `cat` result to `tr` to delete them.

```
  var=$(sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0| tr -d " \t\n")
```

Comment: hmm, probably not.

Comment: It doesnt do anything (nothing happens, I get no return)

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` doesn't return any output. Use `stty` instead

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the whitespaces with the following commands:

```
var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"    
var="${var%"${var##*[![:space:]]}"}"
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)
Thanks for all answers